# Click on number Textview Box and call that number

Tags: android, numbers, call

I want to on click number On Textview box call the number, I knew I need to put my text box clickable its already done, and I need to do a code to put onclick do some stuff but I need help in that part.

This is my `XML` for java class:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Telefone/Fax :  244892501"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

This is my Java class

```
private static Button button1;

ImageView ivImageFromUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    ivImageFromUrl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image_from_url);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i67.tinypic.com/20k9n42.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent NameOfTheIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.docdroid.net/Vh3yPiJ/contatos-lubrifuel.pdf.html"));
        startActivity(NameOfTheIntent);
    }


   })
   ;}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
TextView numTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
numTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel: 244892501"));
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And of course, add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked so that people know that your problem was solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
           callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
           startActivity(callIntent);    
    }
})
```

And don't forget to add permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...It's working for me

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +textView8.getText().toString()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: This will not work. The Uri will now contain **tel:Telefone/Fax :  244892501**

Comment: give the text view input type as Numbers and try

Comment: Yeah, or change the `android:text` I know ur solution works, but not in the way how u have posted it. Than u should have **added** that to your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is a bit messy...**

But to give u a small example of how u can solve ur problem:
U can do something like this:

**XML**

```
<TextView
android:text="Telefone/Fax :  244892501"
android:id="@+id/myTextView"     
android:clickable="true"         <!--Important line-->
<!-- Your other lines -->
/>
```

**Java class**

In your `onCreate()`

```
TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get the phone number
        String myPhoneNr = myTextView.getText().toString();

        //Use this to extract the digits
        myPhoneNr = myPhoneNr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");  //Now only 244892501 remains

        //Start the call
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + myPhoneNr));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**And** like [NEO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807661/4782930) stated: 
Don't forget the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Good luck!